# How to read column values from database table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I`ve tried by doing this:

```
<select name="pageID">
<?php
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `cmspages`";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($row as $field=>$value){
    print<<<HERE
        <option value="$field">$value </option>
HERE;
    }
?>
</select>
```

The table contains the cmsPageID (integer value) and pagaName (text). I`d like to print out only the pagename while still setting the option value to the cmsPageID.

Answer (score -1):

You're only fetching one row, then looping over the columns. You need to call `$result->fetch()` in the loop, then print the specific columns you want.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    print <<<HERE
        <option value="{$row['cmsPageID']}">{$row['pagaName']}</option>
HERE;
}
```

You should also use `SELECT cmsPageID, pagaName` in the query -- don't select columns you're not using.